# python set to unbuffered with -u but still not writing to file until complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

in the beginning of my script post import, i have this line

```
sys.stdout = open(f"{filename}_{timestr}.txt", 'w')
```

there are then a myriad of functions and such are run, essentially scraping AD data, running PS commands, etc.
At the end of my script, i close the file

```
sys.stdout.close()
```

This is entire script is called, successfully, from Task Scheduler on windows, but as a test, I ran the following command in CMD prompt

```
python -u /script.py
```

However, I am only getting contents to the file or steamed using

```
get-content /scriptOUTPUT.txt -wait
```

after the file script is run in its entirety, or more succinctly in my case, when an error present, eg too many connections to LDAP or something.

so my questions are:

1. is there something in the code (sys.stdout.close()) being at the end of the file causing this to happen
2. or is there something else i can do to have it live stream content?  Even placeholder text that I use for more legible log output doesnt show up
3. Is my only option to add sys.stdout.flush() after each function or add a flush=True in my prints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**sys.stdout.write()**

This function writes content to stdout buffer stream and when the buffer is full it will flush content automatically. Or if any content with '\n' then it also flushes. *Ex - sys.stdout.write('This is an example\n')*

**sys.stdout.flush()**

This flush method helpful when we want to flush content manually.

Example 1

```
import sys
import time
  
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

When the above program is executed, then there is no output for the first 9 seconds, then at the 10th, all the 10 numbers from 0 to 9 appear simultaneously.

Example 2

```
import sys
import time
  
for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When the above program is executed, the numbers from 0 to 9 are printed every second on the same line separated by spaces. Since it calling flush after every second.

**sys.stdout.close()**

This close method flushes the remaining contents in the stdout buffer and closes the connection stream. When closing the connection stream first reference the stream to a variable and close it to avoid creating too many connections.

Example

```
ref = sys.stdout
ref.close()
```

Comment: so if i want it to stream how would i change this line, if at all, to live stream to file?

sys.stdout = open(f"{filename}_{timestr}.txt", 'w')

or is it better to add sys.stdout.flush() at the end of each function or print?

Comment: @JustinChe it is better to use flush after each write. For more details you can refer - https://www.askpython.com/python/python-stdin-stdout-stderr